# Operator precendence

Tags: php

There is a problem, I want to loop trought whole stack or stop somewhere, but somehow the loop is throwing out ones instead of counting... item value is wrongly assigned to true, what to do?

```
php7
```

Edit::

Okay... I tried to make it abstract...

```
<?php
class foo {
    private static $instance = [];
    private $stack = [];
    private $stop;
    public static function i() {
        if (!isset(static::$instance[0])) {
            static::$instance[0] = new static();
        }
        return static::$instance[0];
    }
    public static function destroy() {
        unset(static::$instance[0]);
    }
    public function stop() {
        $this->stop = true;
    }
    private function __construct() {
        echo '__constructor being called'.PHP_EOL;
        $this->fillTheVoid();
    }
    public function do() {
        echo 'BEGIN'.PHP_EOL;
        $this->work();
        echo 'END'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    private function fillTheVoid() {
        $k = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < 20 ; $i++) {
            $this->stack[] = ++$k;
        }
    }
    private function work() {
        while($item = array_pop($this->stack) && !$this->stop) {
            echo $item.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

$foo = foo::i();
$foo -> do();
function shutdown() {
    echo 'shutting_down'.PHP_EOL;
    $foo = foo::i();
    $foo -> stop();
    for($i = 3; $i > 0; $i--) {
        sleep(1);
        echo $i.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown', null);

exit;
?>
```

Output is:

```
__constructor being called
BEGIN
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
END
shutting_down
3
2
1
```

Somehow this is looping wrong

We wanted to count, instead we just get ones...

This originated as problem with constructor, but I stumbled on wrongly syntax later, so I changed it a little bit...

Comment: If it its truly singleton, don't worry it will return same object, you don't have to worry about it

Comment: Could you post the code from the singleton and the shutdown function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, your singleton works as intended, constructor is only called once.

Regarding your other problem (getting a buch of 1 instead of a countdown from 20 to 1), here is the fix :

```
private function work() {
    while(($item = array_pop($this->stack)) && !$this->stop) {
        echo 'item:' . $item.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

You need to surround you assignation with parenthesis otherwise it gets evaluated as follows :

```
$item = (array_pop($this->stack) && !$this->stop)
```

Which will return true and be displayed as "1" in you output.